# Can't create array with constant size ("expected constant expression”)

Tags: c, visual-studio

This question pertains to C in Visual Studio (Community 2015) on Windows 10.

I can't seem to create an array with a const size - the below code causes an "expected constant expression" error that prevents build. It's a wchar_t array here with a size_t size, but I see the same behavior for char & other array types & int constants.

I know the size of arrays needs to be known at compile time, but surely that's the case here. What gives?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    size_t const newsize = 100;

    wchar_t fileData[newsize];
}
```

Comment: In this case: why not simply `wchar_t fileData[100];`?

Comment: I've gone and given it a malloc for now - I'll carry on with either that or hard code in the array size in all likelihood since this seems like a "that's how it works" situation. I'd like to know why this is the case though!

Comment: MSVC doesn’t support “variable length arrays”, where the array size is specified by a runtime variable.  The `const` qualifier does not make it a *constant expression* (something which can be evaluated at compile time).  So if you want to specify size at runtime, you’re stuck with using `malloc` or `calloc` on MSVC.  If you want to use VLAs, you’ll have to use a different compiler like MinGW or gcc in a Cygwin environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know the size of arrays needs to be known at compile time, but surely that's the case here.

That's actually not the case. In C, `const` qualifying doesn't result in a "constant expression". So `newsize` isn't a [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression) (unlike C++).

Your code is valid in C99 and in C11, if [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA) is supported by your implementation (VLAs are optional in C11). However, it seems Visual studio doesn't seem to support VLAs and expects a "constant expression" for array size as in C89.

So you may have to use dynamic memory allocation (malloc & friends), or simply specify the `100` as size, or use a macro for defining size and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a const-qualified type is not the same as a constant literal.

You have a couple of options in MSVC. First, you can hardcode `100`:

```
#define SIZE 100

int main(void) // main returns int etc etc
{
    wchar_t fileData[SIZE];
}
```

Or, you can create the array using dynamic memory allocation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
     const size_t newsize = 100;
     wchar_t *fileData;
     fileData = calloc(sizeof filedata, newsize);
}
```

Note that you *can* do `const size_t newsize = 100; wchar_t fileData[newsize];` in C99, but MSVC still doesn't support that fully.

Comment: Your last line seems to be the answer (except that I think it must `const int newsize=100;`)